# Apparent global scope leak in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I'm seeing a really weird issue with this code and sample execution: https://gist.github.com/720278

The data in the two files is identical, but for some reason the app fails on the second file. Running the app only for this file works fine, it only breaks when multiple files are processed in one execution. The exceptions are not helping me track things down at all (complaining about map()s which work fine normally).

I was hoping someone might have seen something like this before and could point me in the right direction.

Comment: I get a different error, on line 49, "can't convert nil into Float (TypeError)"

Comment: & wdebeum, what version of ruby are each of you using?

Comment: I tried both JRuby 1.5.2 with the --1.9 option and MRI 1.8.7, and got the same error (though MRI reported it coming from `log10` and JRuby from `convert_fluxes_to_magnitudes!`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works in MRI 1.9, but not in MRI 1.8.7.  The problem, in this case, comes from a difference in how string subscripting works.

```
def split_comments!
  @comments = @input_data.select { |line| line[0] == "#" }
  parse_header_attributes
  @input_data.delete_if { |line| line[0] == "#" }
end
```

This method intends to separate comments from data by examining the first character of each line using `line[0]`.  In Ruby 1.9, this returns the first character as a string.  in Ruby <1.9, however, this returns the first character as an integer.  For this to work in older versions of ruby, use `line[0..0]` instead of `line[0]`:

```
def split_comments!
  @comments = @input_data.select { |line| line[0..0] == "#" }
  parse_header_attributes
  @input_data.delete_if { |line| line[0..0] == "#" }
end
```

You may find it more succinct to use a regular expression to test for a comment: `line =~ /^#/`.  The method `Array#partition` will also play well here:

```
def split_comments!
  @comments, @input_data = @input_data.partition do |line|
    line =~ /^#/
  end
  parse_header_attributes
end
```

---

With your updates to the git tree, it runs for me without error, when processing multiple files, and when running twice in a row.

Comment: I think `line[0, 1]` is better than `line[0..0]`, since it doesn't require the creation of a Range. I've certainly seen it more often.

Comment: @Chuck, Unless the code is known to be too slow, whichever is better for the human should be preferred.  I'd vote for the regexp and forgo the subscripts.

Comment: I'd never come across #partition before, that is so useful, thanks :)

Comment: @Wayne Conrad: I don't see any particular benefit for humans in either one. They both have roughly equivalent complexity, neither is more surprising than the other and neither is known to prevent gum disease. The only possible "human" argument I can think of is that the `[0, 1]` form is more common in code I've seen and thus more likely to be familiar. But eh, I don't suppose it makes a huge difference.

Comment: @Chuck, I agree.  There are a lot of ways to skin this cat.

Comment: Ok, so I'm fully aware of the issues with string[i], and I'm using 1.9.2 with no trouble. I'm not concerned about backward compatibility with 1.8.7, though I may switch to a regex.As I say, the code works fine for one run, but if I pass multiple file paths at the command line, I get the exception detailed on the second file. The first is always processed fine, even when they are identical.

Comment: Wayne, gistfile2.txt is a paste straight from my terminal. I don't understand what you mean by corrupted.

Comment: @Ben Langfeld, gistfile2.txt contains the console output from an execution of converter.rb, with a stack trace.  Please see above.  I haven't been able to reproduce the problem you have with multiple runs.  I may need more information, such the specific command lines you are using to trigger the error.

Comment: Gist updated. I know gistfile2.txt is console output, that's what it was supposed to be. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Ben Langfeld, I feel like such a dummy.  I assumed that gistfile2.txt was a second input file, due to its similar name, and thought it had been overwritten by accident.  Sorry for the confusion.